# Ampscript for Footer Content

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dynamic, getcontent

I have about four footer variations that we use at the bottom of our email templates. I've been trying to place the various footers in:

**MyContents\Company_Footers\FooterNameHere**

An example footer might look like this:

```
<!-- BEGIN FOOTER -->
<table align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" class="responsive-table">
    <tr>
        <td style="font-family:Arial, Sans-serif; font-size:10px; color:#3d4651; line-height:18px; text-align: center; padding: 10px;">
            Copyright &copy; 2017 %%Member_Busname%%<br>
            %%Member_Addr%% %%Member_City%%, %%Member_State%%, %%Member_PostalCode%% <br>
            International: 407.000.0000 USA &amp; Canada: 866.000.0000
            <br><br>
            Past results are not necessarily indicative of future results.<br>
            <a href="http://risk-disclaimer-link" style="font-size: 10px; color: #288dc1;">RISK DISCLAIMER</a> | <a href="http://general-disclaimer-link" style="font-size: 10px; color: #288dc1;">GENERAL DISCLAIMER</a> | <a href="%%unsub_center_url%%" style="font-size: 10px; color: #288dc1;" target="_blank">UNSUBSCRIBE</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- END FOOTER -->
```

Within my HTML, I am trying to pull that footer in via Ampscript like this:
`%%=ContentAreaByName("my contents\EM_Footers\GenFooter")=%%`

I recall doing it this way with a previous employer but something is missing because SFMC keeps giving me the following error message when I do a Send Preview against a data extension:

> **Unable to generate preview**
>   The email is missing a valid physical mailing address, which must be present on commercial emails per the federal CAN-SPAM Act. Please add a valid postal address in your account settings, or modify your email to include these fields, then you may resend your email.
>
> - For HTML Paste emails, please select 'Physical Mailing Address' under 'Email Tools' to insert the physical mailing address in HTML version of the email.
> - The recommended format for the physical mailing address in the TEXT version of your email is the following:
>     This email was sent by:
>     %%Member_Busname%%
>     %%Member_Addr%%
>     %%Member_City%%, %%Member_State%%, %%Member_PostalCode%%, %%Member_Country%%
> - For Template based emails, your footer should already have the physical mailing address.

What do I need to do to avoid this error?  I know I've been able to get it to work before but I'm missing a step somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best thing is to add all of the required fields.  SFMC Support can disable the check, which is appropriate in some circumstances.  Or you can add this little snippet to your email code to bypass it:

```
%%[ if 0 == 1 then ]%% 
%%Member_Busname%%
%%Member_Addr%%
%%Member_City%%
%%Member_State%%
%%Member_PostalCode%%
%%Member_Country%%
%%[ endif ]%%
```

Comment: Wow!  That did it!  Thank you so much!  I'll start including this at the top of all of my templates.

Comment: Does it work for Content Builder ? I added the snippet but when I disable the footer via a Delivery Profile I got an error when publishing the TSD.