# Problem with HTML Footer

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, html

I have a problem with my HTML footer custom where the problem is below.

My code has all field and i already tried to use inside the code the solution that i saw in the case: '[Ampscript for Footer Content](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/173558/ampscript-for-footer-content?rq=1)'

My code i tried:

```
%%[ if 0 == 1 then ]%%
<span> %%Member_Busname%% <br> 
%%Member_Addr%%, %%Member_City%%, %%Member_State%%, %%Member_PostalCode%%
%%Member_Country%%<br><br> %%[ endif ]%%
```

> The email is missing a valid physical mailing address, which must be present on commercial emails per the federal CAN-SPAM Act. Please add a valid postal address in your account settings, or modify your email to include these fields, then you may resend your email.
>    - For HTML Paste emails, please select 'Physical Mailing Address' under 'Email Tools' to insert the physical mailing address in HTML version of the email.
>    - The recommended format for the physical mailing address in the TEXT version of your email is the following:
>    This email was sent by:
>    %%Member_Busname%%
>    %%Member_Addr%%
>    %%Member_City%%, %%Member_State%%, %%Member_PostalCode%%, %%Member_Country%%
>    - For Template based emails, your footer should already have the physical mailing address.

Comment: Where did you enter the footer script - in the email itself, or in the footer in Admin in Email Studio?

Comment: @CodeRage admin in email studio

Comment: What is the purpose of the if statement around all this? It obviously doesn't evaluate to true and won't include anything in your email. Have you tried without this?

Comment: is this HTML Paste or Template Based? HTML paste do not use the default UI Header/Footer, so if you saved it in the admin section, it would not affect HTML Paste emails.

Comment: Template Based, @Gortonington.

Comment: your html is invalid - perhaps do a closing `</span>` prior to your endif to make it valid. Maybe that is causing the issue? Doubt it, but worth a shot.

Comment: Nothing done: /

Comment: Joao, I've used this workaround quite often as well. Do not put this in your Admin tab and instead add it to your template/html emails in the footer. Also, you should go ahead and put in a ticket with SFMC support to remove this functionality if you don't want it (will be using your own footer that complies with CAN-SPAM)

Comment: I believe you entered this code into a text area and not inside a html code. Delete the text and poste the code without a span in a html block

Answer (score 1):

I used this in the email template directly and there I found out, that you need to check the HTML and Text version of your email. I already encountered this issue when everything seemed right in the HTML-version, however the snipped wasn't added to the text version, so I had to add it separately there.

Another option is requesting to deactivate the check of this information by creating a salesforce support case.