# footer on emails still appearing despite I have disabled on Account Settings

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

We have a content builder templates and on the preview feature those are okay and the system-footer doesn't appear

However when the email is triggered and we are sure the content is published, the email comes with this default footer.

I have tried to do a custom one but neither this works. If I disable it, I add [this code](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/173558/ampscript-for-footer-content?rq=1) to bypass the SPAM-CAM check. But anyway, the footer still appears.

This is the default footer with the salesforce image.

What I want is to disable such default/system footer. I don't need it and I'm looking on how to remove it.

Comment: How do you disable the footer?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the setting for the footer to "none" in the account settings or in the Sender Profile that is used for the send.

- [Account setting](https://dreamevent.secure.force.com/articleView?id=mc_es_headers_footers.htm&type=5) in Setup
- [Delivery Profile](https://www.dummies.com/business/marketing/email-campaigns-salesforce-marketing-cloud-sender-delivery-profiles-send-classifications/) in Setup > Apps > Email Studio (or Email Studio > Administration)

Sorry for the rather unusual links but the Salesforce Help site is currently having loading issues.